# inheritance and constructor arguments from a superclass

Tags: c++

I need a constructor to take as arguments data from a superclass

```
class PetrolCar : public Car{
public:

        Car(string Brand, string LicensePlate, uint16_t YearOfFabrication, double AverageConsumption, uint32_t NumberOfKilometers) : PetrolCar (string Brand, string LicensePlate, uint16_t YearOfFabrication, double AverageConsumption, uint32_t NumberOfKilometers)
```

And I get the following error:

> error: expected ‘)’ before ‘Brand’

Any idea why is that?

Comment: It works the other way around. The PetrolCar constructor shares its arguments with Car's so the object is first initialized as a Car before being further constructed as a PetrolCar. The reason you get your error is that the compiler has no idea what to do with a Car initializer outside of the body of the Car class.

Comment: After fixing the issue above, you need to remove the types when calling base class ctor.

Comment: Is it clear? This is what your code should look like `PetrolCar(string Brand, string LicensePlate, uint16_t YearOfFabrication, double AverageConsumption, uint32_t NumberOfKilometers) : Car(Brand, LicensePlate, YearOfFabrication, AverageConsumption, NumberOfKilometers) { ... }`

Comment: @Moige you should really have posted that as an answer. there are people on this site that pick the solution up from comments and present it as their own work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to be calling the `Car` constructor inside `PetrolCar` constructor like that. You're supposed to be calling the superclass constructor inside the child constructor, if that made sense. Here's what your code is supposed to be looking like:

```
class PetrolCar : public Car {
public:
    PetrolCar(string Brand, string LicensePlate, uint16_t YearOfFabrication, double AverageConsumption, uint32_t NumberOfKilometers)
        : Car(Brand, LicensePlate, YearOfFabrication, AverageConsumption, NumberOfKilometers) {
        // Rest of the constructor code
    }
};
```

Here, I've changed
`PetrolCar(Brand, LicensePlate, YearOfFabrication, AverageConsumption, NumberOfKilometers)`
to
`Car(Brand, LicensePlate, YearOfFabrication, AverageConsumption, NumberOfKilometers)`
and vice versa..